# Can I update a filter with vba on a protected sheet without UserInterfaceOnly:=True?

Tags: excel, vba

Is it possible to use a macro to update a filter on a protected sheet wihtout using UserInterfaceOnly:=True?

I'm using the "Worksheet_Activate" macro to update my filter everytime I enter a new sheet. But if the sheet is protected, I need to add code in my macro that (i) unprotect sheet, (ii) update filter and then (iii) protect sheet.

My goal is to remove the code with protecting and unprotecting as it slows down the macro.

I understand that one solution is to use "UserInterfaceOnly:=True" when the sheet is protected. However, I don't consider this a good solution since this attribute is not saved when the file is closed. Meaning that as soon as I open the file again, I need to run a "unprotect/protect" loop.

Note:

If i simply try to update the filter with code such as:

```
ActiveSheet.Range("$CC$10:$CD$525").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="=1", Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:="="
```

I get an error stating: "Run-time error'1004': You cannot use this command on a protected sheet. To use this command, you must first unprotect the sheet...."

This even though the cells have been choosen as not "locked".

This also even though I protect the sheet with "allowfiltering = True":

```
Sub ProtectSheet(Sheet As String)
    Call LoadVariables
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Sheets(Sheet)
    ws.Protect LockPassword, AllowFiltering:=True
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi @cybernetic.nomad, I know. but as stated in my question, my goal is not to do that as it slows done the macro.